# all postfix mail forwarding rejected by my gmail account

Tags: postfix-mta, email-forwarding

I've been using postfix on a digitalocean droplet for years to forward mail from several domains on that server to my gmail address.

Now they're all being blocked by google, with this message:

`Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely
    suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP`

running postfix 2.11. Can't upgrade that either; apparently ubuntu refuses to recognize postfix 3.

Can anyone help? I have no idea which way to turn.

How can I securely forward emails directed to my domains without running into this problem?

Comment: Same issue with me as well.

Comment: I've decided to abandon postfix in favour of a registry service that offers clean mail forwarding -- will migrate my domains to EasyDNS.com. Seems to be the modern way, and Digital Ocean has always recommended against roll-your-own mail forwarding. Now I know why, in spite of the fact that it worked well for years.